Displaying matplotlib.pyplot figure in an .pdf exported from Obsidian note
Obsidian has plugins for executing code which work fine in the software, but when I tried exporting the note to a .pdf file, only the raw code is exported without the figures it is supposed to produce and display...
The code is pretty straightforward, but the diagram is not shown in the exported .pdf, only the raw code block.
phi = np.linspace(np.pi/6, np.pi/3, 100)
ratio_1=(4-2*np.sin(phi))/(1-np.sin(phi))
ratio_2=(1+np.sin(phi))/(1-np.sin(phi))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.rad2deg(phi),ratio_1, label=r"$\frac{\sigma_c}{\sigma_{t}^{'}}$")
ax.plot(np.rad2deg(phi),ratio_2, label=r'$\frac{\sigma_c}{\sigma_{t}}$')
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('Angle of friction')
ax.set_ylabel('Ratio')
plt.show()

I've searched some better export plugins, and other code execution plugins, but have not found any that deal with the problem.

Please share your code as formatted text rather than an image.
